# Javascript array to string returning in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function

I'm extremely new to coding (only my 2nd day with it) and I've been starting with JavaScript because a website I'm using is helping me and I have learning difficulties I won't go into here but I want to at least try to learn as much as I can :). However, I'm on a challenge on this website and I've been hitting a road block for the past few hours on something I'm sure is obvious but I'm at a frustrated point and hoping some of you kind folks can help. The website is using tests to see if the challenges are passed as per the brief.

I've been able to figure out that I need to use [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on the array parts to satisfy the test individually but I'm blanking on how to do them all/call them as per the challenge instructions.

Challenge info **:**

**Create String**
The function `createString` takes an array of strings and should return a string consisting of all the strings in the array with a space in between each one. If the array is empty, it should return an empty string.

```
createString([]);
// should return ''
createString(['hello', 'world']);
// should return 'hello world'
createString(['my', 'name', 'is', 'frank']);
// should return 'my name is frank'
```

This is the starting code

```
function createString (array) {
  // code here
}
```

This is where I got to before my brain melted from frustration:

```
function createString (array) {
  let arr1 = [].join(' ');
  let arr2 = ['hello', 'world'].join(' ');
  let arr3 = ['my', 'name', 'is', 'frank'].join(' ');
  return array;
}

createString();
```

I fully intend to brush up more of the basics but seeing where I'm going wrong with this would help a lot. I think I have to call the function in a way that gives it the right part of the array ?

Please help

Comment: «The function createString takes an array of strings» means you should call it like this: `let resString = createString(['string1', 'string2', 'string3']);` in this example, it should return this string: `string1 string2 string3`

Comment: Consider, step by step, what your function does... First, you declare three new variables and assign hard-coded values/operations to them.  Then, you ignore them and return whatever was passed to the function, unmodified.  You're also calling the function without passing anything to it, even though the instructions specified how the function should be called.

Comment: "array" is the parameter passed to the function. All you need to do is return "array.join(' ')". Maybe into how function parameters work and how functions are called.

Comment: Generally, the way these learning/testing sites work is that you write an implementation of a function, and then the site passes various arguments to the function in order to verify that it passes correctly.  My hunch is you are not expected to yourself return the various outputs given in the example-- instead, write your function to process any array input by joining, and then run the tests, which will themselves pass the args.

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone. I see where I've been going wrong now. Have a good week and stay healthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Few observations as per your current implementation **:***

```
function createString (array) {
  let arr1 = [].join(' ');
  let arr2 = ['hello', 'world'].join(' '); --> Using hard coded data. It should be dynamic as per the passed parameter.
  let arr3 = ['my', 'name', 'is', 'frank'].join(' ');
  return array; --> Returning the same parameter value without making any changes in it.
}

createString(); --> Calling a function without passing a parameter to it.
```

*Here you go with the correct implementation **:***

```js
function createString (arr) {
    return arr.join(' ');
}

const arr1Str = createString([]);
const arr2Str = createString(['hello', 'world']);
const arr3Str = createString(['my', 'name', 'is', 'frank']);

console.log(arr1Str);
console.log(arr2Str);
console.log(arr3Str);
```